# Checking percentage of a value either side of another value

Tags: r, percentage

I have two values (`before` and `after`) and want to check if the difference (change) between `before` and `after` is either less than or equal to or greater than or equal to three percent either way (`+/-3.00%`) of another value (`agreed`).

For example:

```
---------------------------
| Agreed | Before | After |
---------------------------
| 100    | 110    | 85    | (FALSE)
---------------------------
| 350    | 300    | 480   | (FALSE)
---------------------------
| 167    | 166    | 166   | (TRUE)
---------------------------
| 200    | 220    | 206   | (TRUE)
---------------------------
```

Note that the values can indeed be the same in `before` and `after`.  What I want to check for is whether or not the `after` value is three percent either side of `agreed` (`+/-3.00%`).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this which works well for me.

Firstly, I saved the percentage of difference between `after` and `agreed` to a new column (`percentage`), then I checked it against the following and assigned the outcome to a new column (`threePercent`):

```
df$threePercent <- ifelse(df$percentage >= 0.03 | df$percentage <= -0.03, "YES", "NO")
```

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the output you want

```
> agreed = c(100,350,167)
> before = c(110,300,166)
> after = c(85, 480, 165)
> 
> abs(after-before)
[1]  25 180   1
> abs(after-before)/agreed
[1] 0.250000000 0.514285714 0.005988024
> abs(after-before)/agreed<0.03
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```